# Set A5 page size in docx4j-Java

Tags: java, netbeans, docx4j, .doc

I generate a `.doc` file in Java using `docx4j`, and I want to set the page size to a5, but in the list of available options are a3, a4, b4jis, legal, letter but not a5.

Can anyone help me and give me a suggestion how to do that?

I tried to generate with aspose, but there is a trial period, and with apache poi, but it beats me.

**Edit:**
I added the latest version, `docx4j-3.2.2` but still not recognized the A5 format. I used 2 syntaxes that works with A3 and A4 pageSizePaper but not with A5.

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = 
    WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage(
        org.docx4j.model.structure.PageSizePaper.valueOf("A3"), true
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably, You are using an older version. 
As i checked the [GITHUB](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/model/structure/PageSizePaper.java) I, i can see that they have added A5 in PageSizePaper Class. I suggest you to use the latest jar.
PageDimensions class can be used to create a page of your dimension. Just explore a bit.

Comment: Yes, it looks like this should work.  https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/model/structure/PageDimensions.java#L285